# Merge column of a dataframe from row of another data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two different data frames.

```
Id  data
T1  100
T2  250
T3  300


T1  T2  T3 
1   2   3
```

Output I am trying to get

```
Id  data component
T1  100     1
T2  250     2
T3  300     3
```

Comment: If you have data.frames exactly as given then `cbind(df1, t(df2))` will do the task, but I expect that the situation could be more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat1<-data.frame(Id=c("T1","T2","T3"),data=c(100,250,300))
dat2<-data.frame(T1=1,T2=2,T3=3)
```

Just transpose `dat2` using `t(dat2)`

```
data3<-data.frame(dat1,component=t(dat2))


> data3<-data.frame(dat1,component=t(dat2))
> data3
   Id data component
T1 T1  100         1
T2 T2  250         2
T3 T3  300         3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

if df is your first data.frame and vec is your vector (with names "T1","T2","T3")

note that using `match` ensures that everything goes well even if the names are not in the same order in both data.frames.

```
df$component<-vec[match(df$Id,names(vec))] # if vec is a vector

df$component<-unlist(vec[1,match(df$Id,colnames(vec))]) # if vec is a one row data.frame
```

**data** :

```
df<-structure(list(Id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), 
              class = "factor"), data = c(100L, 250L, 300L)), 
              .Names = c("Id","data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

vec<-structure(1:3, .Names = c("T1", "T2", "T3"))
```

**output** :

```
> df
  Id data component
1 T1  100         1
2 T2  250         2
3 T3  300         3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be the following. But, if your data are just like the example, @user2438475 idea is probably the way to go.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(mydf2, variable, component) %>%
left_join(mydf, ., by = c("Id" = "variable"))

#  Id data component
#1 T1  100         1
#2 T2  250         2
#3 T3  300         3
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(Id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3"
        ), class = "factor"), data = c(100L, 250L, 300L)), .Names = c("Id", 
        "data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

mydf2 <- structure(list(T1 = 1L, T2 = 2L, T3 = 3L), .Names = c("T1", "T2", 
         "T3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```